# Notepad++: Search and replace expressions

Tags: notepad++

How can I replace all occurences of “STRING“ (with this quotation marks in the text) in a text by \command{STRING} for any text STRING and a specific command "\command".

That is to simply replace the quotation marks by the command. But ONLY if they are of the form “STRING“, and NOT if the are of the form „STRING“ (opening mark is different, closing the same).

Comment: The default search and replace didn't make the cut? And with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, try something with a regex. You can choose "Regular expression" as the search mode.

The simples search would be `"(.*)"`. The parentheses allow you to reference the found string in your replacement regex. If you want to allow linebreaks in strings, check the checkbox "*.matches newline*".

If you have a text like `"STRING"STRING"` and you only want to match the string in between the first quotation marks, you will need the following regex `"([^"]*)"`. This will also match if your string contains linebreaks. If you don't want that, use `"([^"^\n]*)"`.

The replacement regex would be `\\command{\1}`.

Comment: Better safe-guard against multiple quoted strings on a single line: `"([^"]*)"`, but then this will also only work in if the quoted strings do not break across lines.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I guess it depends on what exactly is the purpose of the search-and-replace query. Something like `"([^"^\n]*)"` might do the trick?

Comment: I'm not sure how Notepad++ handles line-breaks. Conventionally they are never matched in regex, unless you explicitly enable multi-line expressions using some kind of flag. That really depends on the regex-engine Notepad++ is using. There is a *". matches newline"* checkbox, though.

Comment: I just tried, a string with a newline won't be matched by `(.*)`, at least in my Notepad++. I don't see a checkbox ". matches newline".

Comment: There is, you probably should update your Notepad++ installation (`Help->Update Notepad++`). Also, from Notepad++ version 6 on you can use `\r` and `\n` in regular expressions.

Comment: I think I'll just do a clean installation, the 'Update Notepad++' menu option is also missing :S

Comment: I tried it with searching for "([^"]*)", but that does not work properly. It finds the first quotation mark and the last, and takes all between as argument. E.g. it makes <"this is" a very "good"> to <\command{this is" a very "good}>. How to fix this?

Comment: Ok, I see. It depends, where you begin with the search, that is, where the cursor is set, when searching.

Comment: Try with this one: “moralisches Gewissen“ gegeben als auch die Fähigkeit, die hohen menschlichen Werte zu erkennen und eine edle Gesinnung anzustreben und auch erreichen zu können. Falls er in sich hineinschaut, seinen aus dem Himmlischen herrührenden Geist bedenkt und sich selbst, sein “Selbst“, erkennt,

Comment: And change the marks to “, it does not work. As I said, it finds the complete expression, not only from the first to the second mark

Comment: I copied your text to my Notepad and copied the used quotation marks to the regex, and it matches on `“moralisches Gewissen“` and `“Selbst“`. What version of Notepad++ do you have?